# iOS app crashes when first opened by URL Scheme

Tags: ios, ios8, url-scheme, app-startup

My app handles URL Schemes. When it is already running and gets called from another app, it behaves correctly and without a problem. However, when it is completely closed (as in not-in-background-mode), and another app calls it, it crashes immediately.

I've already set the "Wait for executable to be launched" option so I could debug the  `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but it seems that it is not getting called. I've also implemented `-application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` but it seems that its not getting called either.

Here's the crash:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x10a79e278:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax
0x10a79e27d:  movq   %rcx, %r10
0x10a79e280:  syscall 
0x10a79e282:  jae    0x10a79e28c               ; __pthread_kill + 20
0x10a79e284:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x10a79e287:  jmp    0x10a799ca3               ; cerror_nocancel
0x10a79e28c:  retq   
0x10a79e28d:  nop    
0x10a79e28e:  nop    
0x10a79e28f:  nop
```

Any idea on how to solve this, or what am I doing wrong? I'm using iOS 8 GM and Xcode 6 GM.

Comment: Check the console for any errors. There should be some error message there

Comment: The console only shows ``(lldb)``.

Comment: Hmmmm.. If you're testing on a real device you can look at the crash log files. You might be able to gain some insight that way. Sorry I can't be more help :(

Comment: I'm having this identical problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @PhilipArpin — are you testing on a device or simulator?

Comment: Both. But I've seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I fixed it! I just had to check for the following case in my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

            if ((launchOptions) != nil) {

                if ((launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]) != nil){


                }
```

Thanks for the support!